# Multiple Custom Buttons, Only One Displayed Correctlly

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm trying to use some custom buttons on the iOS device. And here is what I did: I added a `UIButton` on Storyboard and changed its type to `Custom`. After that, I changed the default button image under the "Attributes Inspector" tab. Then I used the following two lines of code to set the status of the button:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unclicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

This behaves perfectly on the simulator. Thus I copied this button on storyboard and paste another two. For sure, I removed their reference to `button1` and refer them to another two newly created `UIButton` outlet in the view controller header file and synthesize them in the .m file. And I append the following lines to the above code:

```
    ...
    [self.button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unclicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [self.button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unclicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    ...
```

Everything seems normal on the `Storyboard`. But after I ran the simulator, only the image of `button3` can be displayed correctly. The other two disappeared and showing something like `c..` only. How could I make the three buttons behave correctly? I tried hard but made no progress. Could somebody help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: I would recheck your connections in the StoryBoard and see that everything is wired up right. And then set a breakpoint and see whats happening in the code.

Comment: @nikhitadkslfslg I tried commented all the code and just used the default image set in the inspector using storyboard. And only the image of `button3` displayed correctly. I think there could be something wrong when I paste the other two buttons. But I check the inspector and couldn't find something valuable.

Comment: If you're copying and pasting the buttons in the storyboard, then be sure that it's not copying the connections too (meaning that all three buttons would be set to "button3")

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the "c.." means. It's the title of my button. When the image can't be loaded, the text of your button's title will be displayed instead.

I solved my problem by unchecking the "Use Autolayout" option under the "File Inspector" tab in Xcode. And after I run the simulator without this option checking, the button shows perfectly.

Then after the button image came back, I also noticed that the code seems being rebuilt and all the UI connections from storyboard to my code disappeared. So I reconnect them. Honestly, I don't know the exact reason for this. I guess it's because if you paste the button with "Use Autolayout" checked, then the layout constraints for the newly pasted buttons are not correct. Anyway, I'm still not quite clear about how this happens. Hope somebody who knows this well could explain it.